# YouTube API v3 Not Displaying Exceptions

Tags: java, video, youtube-api, oauth-2.0, youtube-channels

I just started using YouTube API for Java and I'm having a tough time trying to figure out why things don't work since exception/stack trace is no where to be found. What I'm trying to do is to get list of videos uploaded by current user.

```
GoogleTokenResponse tokenFromExchange = new GoogleTokenResponse();
tokenFromExchange.setAccessToken(accessToken);

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY).setTransport(TRANSPORT).build();
credential.setFromTokenResponse(tokenFromExchange);

YouTube.Channels.List channelRequest = youtube.channels().list("contentDetails");
channelRequest.setMine(true);
channelRequest.setFields("items/contentDetails,nextPageToken,pageInfo");
ChannelListResponse channelResult = channelRequest.execute();
```

I don't see anything wrong with this code and also tried removing multiple things, but still not able to get it to work. Please let me know if you have run into a similar issue. The version of client library I'm using is v3-rev110-1.18.0-rc.

Comment: You don't provide the part of your code where you get the accessToken. Could the problem be in your oAuth flow? Could you add those parts in? Also take a look at the "retrieve my uploads" sample code in the docs to see if that might help (as it makes a similar call): https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#retrieve_my_uploads

Comment: I'm able to get information about the current user with the access token so I don't think that's the issue. I will double check the permission string again. Either way, I'm wondering why it doesn't print anything out when it's not working.

Comment: The status code of channelResult would be 400 or 403 if the request was rejected on YouTube's end. But it is odd if channelResult is just completely empty. channelResult.getItems() returns an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube API has some working code and you can use it.

```
public static YouTubeService service;
public static String USER_FEED = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/";
public static String CLIENT_ID = "...";
public static String DEVELOPER_KEY = "...";

public static int getVideoCountOf(String uploader) {
    try {
        service = new YouTubeService(CLIENT_ID, DEVELOPER_KEY);
        String uploader = "UCK-H1e0S8jg-8qoqQ5N8jvw"; // sample user
        String feedUrl = USER_FEED + uploader + "/uploads";
        VideoFeed videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(feedUrl), VideoFeed.class);
        return videoFeed.getTotalResults();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(YouTubeCore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This simple give you the number of videos a user has. You can read through **videoFeed** using **printEntireVideoFeed** prepared on their api page.